# Referencing custom component's design-time assembly

Tags: c#, .net, components, custom-component, design-time

I'm trying to decouple custom component's run-time and design-time part (so the run-time can use .NET 4.0 Client Profile and the design time will use full 4.0 framework).

I have all the design related classes in separate assembly which references the run-time assembly and the run-time assembly only references the design time assembly by string:

```
[Designer("MyCompany.MyComponents.ComponentDesigner, MyCompany.MyComponents")]
[ToolboxItem("MyCompany.MyComponents.ComponentToolboxItem, MyCompany.MyComponents")]
```

The problem is, after dragging the component from toolbox, Visual Studio complaints that it is unable to create toolbox item.

All classes are public. Run-time assembly DOES NOT reference design-time assembly.

Have you experienced / solved something similar?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Last time I developed a design time component, I used another instance of visual studio to debug it with the first instance attached to the second.

helpful tips: bugs in design-time constructors are bad. I don't know whether it's still true, but visual studio loses track of design-time vs run-time of you are working with nested controls.